# How to access thumbnail cache of vista and 7 using c#

Tags: c#, windows-7, caching, windows-vista, thumbnails

I wanted to access the thumb cache of vista and 7 to be used in my ImageList. I know how to do it in XP by means of the thumbs.db files, but in vista and 7 the thumbs.db is not present so how will i do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use IShellItemImageFactory::GetImage().

.NET interop is here.
http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Interfaces.IShellItemImageFactory

There is also a sample using Direct2D and this interface on msdn.microsoft.com.

Comment: tried it but i keep getting an ArgumentException in this line:

SHCreateItemFromParsingName(filename, IntPtr.Zero, uuid, out ppsi);

Comment: i forgot to remove the '@' on each filename. it is working now thanks for the link...